# Odd text starting position on a JQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

So I have a page that shows a lot of info via JQuery UI dialogs but it displays the text mid scroll. So it is a terms and conditions bloc of html and whenever I open the dialog to show it it shows said block of HTML scrolled to the middle instead of from the top. You can see it at http://tequilanock.com by clicking the link in the footer that reads "términos y condiciones". I'ts in Spanish but I don't think it matters. You can see that the text does not appear from the beginning and you have to scroll yourself to the top. What might be causing this?

Comment: I see what you mean (using Chrome as well).  Not sure what is causing it, but if you run into a brick wall, you can always use .scrollTop(0) to set it to the top.

Comment: Cool. Let me try that! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to accept your comment as the correct answer? It fixed the issue.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, but if you find the cause of the problem, please update this post; I'm kind of curious.

Comment: Ok. I'll keep on looking after I finish some other stuff. BUt for now it does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .scrollTop(0) can set the scroll to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine in Chrome, what browser has issues?

Comment: Actually Chrome. But you see the text shown in the dialog from the beginning? I see it scrolled to the middle and have to scroll it back manually to the beginning. My clients have tested it in firefox and safari with the same result.

Comment: I'm getting the same in Firefox

Comment: Really? Everyone else here is getting something like this: https://i.minus.com/iGhKsyDfyof04.png Check the scroll bar. It's in the middle of the text. Not at the beginning.

Comment: The only link that works correctly is "Políticas y Privacidad".